# Real analysis metric

Tags: real-analysis

[image: Real analysis help please!]

Let Sn = to the summation of that equation, I know that since this is an increasing sequence and it is bounded above, then it must converge. But how do I prove that it's a metric? It's a metric if it satisfies the 3 conditions symmetry, positivity, and the triangle inequality. Please help!

Comment: Which properties of a metric and you having trouble proving?

Comment: I am trying to prove the triangle inequality, which I do not how to start.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to prove is the transitivity property: for any three sequences X = {x(n)}, Y = {y(n)}, and Z = {z(n)}: d(X,Y) < d(X,Z) + d(Z,Y). You can do this by proving the following inequality for three positive real numbers:

If a, b, c > 0 and a < b + c then a/(1 + a) < b/(1 + b) + c/(1 + c). But this is easy:

since: f(x) = x/(1 + x) has f'(x) = 1/(1 + x)^2 > 0, f is an increasing function. So f(a) < f(b + c) if 0 < a < b + c. Thus a/(1 + a) < (b + c)/(1 + b + c) = b/(1 + b + c) + c/(1 + b + c) < b/(1 + b) + c/(1 + c).